# Accessing interface/class of a nested module in TypeScript

Tags: module, typescript

I've got a TS module that holds an inner module, such as:

```
module abc.customer.ratings {

  module abc.customer.ratings.bo {
    export interface RatingScale {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      type: string;
    }
  }

  var scale: ??? // how to name the inner interface here?
}
```

I've tried to use:

- `RatingScale`, just the name - **failed**
- `bo.RatingScale` - the inner module name (like a relative path) + just the name - **failed**
- `abc.customer.ratings.bo.RatingScale` - full module path from the beginning of the world - **worked**

My question is - can I use this in any shorter way, because the one that works is really verbose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code:

```
module abc.customer.ratings {

  module abc.customer.ratings.bo {
    export interface RatingScale {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      type: string;
    }
  }

  var scale: ??? // how to name the inner interface here?
}
```

The fully-qualified name of `RatingScale` is `abc.customer.ratings.abc.customer.ratings.bo.RatingScale`. What you probably wanted to write was:

```
module abc.customer.ratings {

  module bo {
    export interface RatingScale {
      id: number;
      name: string;
      type: string;
    }
  }

  var scale: bo.RatingScale;
}
```

Comment: That answer was definitely worth more than just one upvote ;)